# Makefile to create subdirectories and download some files by a file of ID list

Tags: linux, bash, makefile, gnu-make

#### Description

I am writing GNU make Makefile to download some files from server (L1.txt, L2.txt, ...). I have a target to make each of them or all of them.

Each file consists of ID list.

For each List File (L1.txt, L2.txt, ...) I would like to create a sub-directory with the same name as List File (ex, L1.txt -> ./L1, ..) - easy :).

Then for each list file, for each ID in the list file I would like to download other file to a particular directory (directory created by list file) and process it to make some binary file. All binary files at each sub directory should be aggregated to other .merged.bin - complicated :/

#### Example

L1.txt:

```
10, 20, 30
```

L2.txt:

```
101, 102, 105
```

So after make I would like to have:

```
./L1.merged.bin
./L2.merged.bin
./conf/L1.txt
./conf/L2.txt

./data/L1/10.txt
./data/L1/20.txt
./data/L1/30.txt
./data/L1/10.bin
./data/L1/20.bin
./data/L1/30.bin

./data/L2/101.txt
./data/L2/102.txt
./data/L2/105.txt
./data/L2/101.bin
./data/L2/102.bin
./data/L2/105.bin
```

#### Sample code

```
LIST_FILES=$(wildcard conf/*.txt)
LIST_FOLDERS=$(patsubst conf/%.txt, data/%, ${LIST_FILES})
MERGED_FILES=$(patsubst conf/%.txt, %.merged.bin, ${LIST_FILES})

all: mergesubs


mergesubs: ${MERGED_FILES} 

conf/%: 
    curl -sSL some-list-url/$*.txt > $@

data/%: conf/%.txt
    test -d $@ || mkdir $@

# PSEUDO CODE STARTS HERE:
# template code to understand inner-workings.
# should not work as target should be made for each data sub directory.
data/*/%.bin: data/*/%.txt
     my_process $< > $@

data/*/%.txt:
    curl -sSL someurl/$* > $@

# PROBLEMS START HERE!
# prerequisite should be a list of files, 
# with file extension .bin and generated from list file 
# provided before. conf/L1.txt might be not downloaded
# so I need to add it to prerequisites, 
# but make does not provide ordering for prerequisites
# Something similar
%.merged.bin: $(shell cat conf/%.txt) conf/%
    cat $^ > $@
```

#### Question

How can I write dependency tree for such a situation?
I would like to keep all gnu make's good qualities: download files only once, process them only once and etc..

#### P.S.

Please do not suggest another tool than GNU Make as I need to do this with Makefile in linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few comments before you read my code:

Don't use `$(wildcard)` - it is a bad idea all around.  List the items you expect, like I did in `LIST_FILE_STEMS`

Appending `/.` is a good way to tell Make this is a directory (appending just `/` is not enough - Make strips it). However, the way I did the rule for `%/.` here, only works reliably for directories created when the parent exists.  That's because `mkdir -p` suffers from subtle race conditions with parent directories. In your case, you only create one level directories, so it is OK.

When downloading remote files, there is no point in depending on the remote file, as its timestamp cannot be ascertained without first downloading it.  So in such cases, one good way to proceed, which I did here, is to only download, if the local copy does not exist.  If you want to force re-download, then you have to delete the local copy first.

Any non-trivial recipe should depend on the `Makefile` so if the recipe changes, the target rebuilds.

There are some subtle techniques I employ here, which are not immediately obvious, if you are not experienced, when you read the code.  But when you try to change the code, it may "stop working" because you did not realize what is happening.  That will be an opportunity for you to learn at that point - GNU Make manual is your friend :)  So that's why I did not specifically comment the code.

Remember to replace spaces with leading tabs in the recipes before trying my code - as far as I know, there is no way to paste tabs in code in Stack Overflow - it changes tabs to spaces.

Here you go:

```
LIST_FILE_STEMS := \
    L1 \
    L2 \

LIST_FILES := $(patsubst %, conf/%.txt, $(LIST_FILE_STEMS))

MERGED_FILES := $(patsubst conf/%.txt, %.merged.bin, $(LIST_FILES))

GENERATED_MAKEFILES := $(addsuffix _Makefile, $(LIST_FILE_STEMS))

all: $(MERGED_FILES)

-include $(GENERATED_MAKEFILES)

$(GENERATED_MAKEFILES): %_Makefile: conf/%.txt Makefile
    echo $*.merged.bin: $(patsubst %, data/$*/%.bin, $(shell sed 's/,//g' < $<)) > $@

%.merged.bin:
    cat $^ > $@

$(LIST_FILES): Makefile
    curl -sSL $(subst conf,some-list-url,$@) > $@

%/.:
    mkdir -p $@

.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.bin: %.txt Makefile | $$(dir $$@).
    my_process $< > $@

data/%.txt: Makefile | $$(dir $$@).
    curl -sSL someurl/$(notdir $*).txt > $@
```